# Android bootanimation doesn't work (permissions error)

Tags: android, permissions, boot

Recently I designed my own android bootanimation.zip file. I'm very proud of it and would like to make it my boot animation (the graphic that shows up when you start up your phone). However, I ran into a complication that I can't seem to solve or find any solutions to online.

Info: I'm running Cyanogen 12 on a Motorola Nexus 6. I placed my bootanimation.zip in the /system/media folder (and /data/local, but that didn't work).

The issue (read carefully please!):
I have confirmed that my bootanimation.zip file IS formatted correctly and DOES display properly. When I enter my phone's shell as root I can properly execute the /system/bin/bootanimation command. This command simply previews bootanimation. However, I can't execute the binary as non-root (which I should be able to do). I even went as far as changing the ownership of bootanimation to the shell (non-root account). Basically, I see something like this.

```
shell> bootanimation #/system/bin/bootanimation should by in my $PATH
/system/bin/sh: bootanimation: not found
shell> cd /system/bin
shell:/system/bin> ls bootanimation
bootanimation: Permission denied
shell:system/bin> ./bootanimation
/system/bin/sh: ./bootanimation: not found

shell:system/bin> su #log in as root
root> cd /system/bin
root:/system/bin> ls -l bootanimation
-rwxr-xr-x shell    shell       34252 2015-11-03 11:07 bootanimation
```

Finally, the device is clearly unable to execute this on startup because the boot animation is never displayed, instead a silver 'google' is displayed.

I appreciate any input, thanks.

Comment: This question is not about programming. Therefore, it's off-topic, for this site.

Comment: Thanks, I reposted it on xda. Link here for anyone interested: http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/help/android-bootanimation-doesnt-t3241214